# What is "the function name regex" for git log -L :<funcname>:<file>

Tags: swift, git

I have the following Swift function in my file `Main/VProj/AppModel.swift`

```swift
    func createItemAndSegment(image:UIImage, completionHandler:(Item?, NSError?)->Void) {
        \\[...]
    }
```

The documentation for [`git log -L :<funcname>:<file>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/) states

> **-L <start>,<end>:<file>**
>
> **-L :<funcname>:<file>**
>
> Trace the evolution of the line range given by "<start>,<end>" (or the 
>   function name regex <funcname>) within the <file>.

But the commands

- `git log -L :createItemAndSegment:Main/VProj/AppModel.swift`
- `git log -L :'createItemAndSegment':Main/VProj/AppModel.swift`
- `git log -L :'/createItemAndSegment/':Main/VProj/AppModel.swift`

all fail with the error `starting at line 1: no match`

When the documentation says `:<funcname>` is the "function name regex", what should it look like?

Answer (score 16):

The `funcname` should be a regular expression that matches the function name, and a literal string with no special regular expression characters should be a valid regular expression, so your first example, `git log -L :createItemAndSegment:Main/VProj/AppModel.swift`, should work.

However, in order for it to work, Git needs to be able to determine which lines are function declarations. It has a default regular expression that assumes that any line that begins with an alphabetic character, underscore, or dollar sign (with no leading whitespace) is the start of a function declaration, and using the `-L :<funcname>:<file>` syntax will be searching for a function declaration that also matches your pattern, up to the next function declaration or end of file.

In some languages, this heuristic is not appropriate. For instance, if function or method declarations are nested inside of a class and thus indented, it will not pick up on these declarations. For this, you need to define a custom function header regex. The [`.gitattributes` section "Defining a custom hunk-header"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header) describes how to do this. First, you would create a `.gitattributes` file at the top level of your project that contains something like:

```
*.swift diff=swift
```

Then in your `.git/config`, or your global `~/.gitconfig`, you would define a regex for how to find these declarations. I don't know enough of Swift to be able to tell you for sure what the appropriate regex is, but it might be something like the following (which I based on the [built in regex for Python](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/userdiff.c?id=f3adf457e046f92f039353762a78dcb3afb2cb13#n112)):

```
[diff "swift"]
    xfuncname = ^[ \t]*((class|func)[ \t].*)$
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I wonder if it would be better for me to swap to using the <start>,<end> regexes instead of :<funcname>. I'd assumed that the latter would avoid me having to get my head around regexes for Swift, but it seems not. [I have posted](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/96195) over on the Apple developper forums (my post's awaiting moderator approval) just-in-case there is anyone there who could add Swift to the built in git regexes you mention.

Comment: Can we not just incorporate the whitespace regex into the function name regex? eg. '\\s+func...'. I'm actually curious -- I've been trying with ruby files like '\\s+def load' to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I met the same situation when trying to explain how to trace a JS function in a class using `git log -L`.
I ended up using the `<start><end>:<file>` syntax. The only problem was to find the right syntax for the `<end>` matcher in order to specify the exact indentation.

Here is an example:

`git log -L '/myFunction (params) {/','/^  }/':myClass.js`

I you read the official example in the man page, you've seen that syntax:

`git log -L '/int main/',/^}/:main.c`

If you try that one with my previous example you'll get an error:

```
$ git log -L '/myFunction (params) {/',/^  }/:myClass.js

fatal: Invalid object name '}/'.
```

The solution is to use (single) quotes around the `<end>` expression: `/^  }/`=> `'/^  }/'`.

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

> The `funcname` should be a regular expression that matches the function name

Make sure said `funcname` is not `$`, or that would trigger an **infinite loop**, as documented in "[Why does '`$`' for funcname in `git log -L` cause an infinite search?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74690545/6309)".

[larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) proposed a patch which should be part of Git 2.40 (Q1 2023).

When given a pattern that matches an empty string at the end of a line, the code to parse the "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3f2e4c09c769dc2fbbabfcfa625451f9d98bd49a/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> line-ranges fell into an infinite loop, which has been corrected with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023).

See [commit 4e57c88](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e57c88e028c25ee9428b51ff829299bbb88a80c) (19 Dec 2022) by [Lars Kellogg-Stedman (`larsks`)](https://github.com/larsks).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3f2e4c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f2e4c09c769dc2fbbabfcfa625451f9d98bd49a), 02 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`line-range`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e57c88e028c25ee9428b51ff829299bbb88a80c): fix infinite loop bug with '`$`' regex
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Lars Kellogg-Stedman</sup>

> When the `-L` argument to "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4e57c88e028c25ee9428b51ff829299bbb88a80c/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> is passed the zero-width regular expression `$`" (as in "`-L :$:`[`line-range.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4e57c88e028c25ee9428b51ff829299bbb88a80c/line-range.c)"), this results in an infinite loop in `find_funcname_matching_regexp()`.
>
> Modify `find_funcname_matching_regexp` to correctly match the entire line instead of the zero-width match at eol and update the loop condition to prevent an infinite loop in the event of other undiscovered corner cases.
>
> The primary change is that we pre-decrement the beginning-of-line marker ('`bol`') before comparing it to '`\n`'.
> In the case of '`$`', where we match the '`\n`' at the end of the line and start the loop with `bol == eol`, this ensures that `bol` will find the beginning of the line on which the match occurred.

You will now get:

```bash
$ git log -L :$:main.go
fatal: -L parameter '$' starting at line 1: no match
```