# Why does '$' for funcname in git log -L cause an infinite search?

Tags: regex, git

You can search for a filename and function name in git log with `git log -L :funcname:filename`.

I ran into an issue where we had been running this search programmatically and the funcname was set to '$', which caused an endless search. (e.g. `git log -L :$:somefile.py`)

'$' means end of string in regex, but why does this cause an endless search loop when other regex characters like '^' or '?' don't? What unique effects does the '$' character have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this locally and step through the code using `gdb`.

This looks like a bug in the [`find_funcname_match_regexp` function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/805265fcf7a737664a8321aaf4a0587b78435184/line-range.c#L133). It eventually ends up matching `$` against the empty string, which matches successfully but causes no changes in the pointers used to mark the position in the file, resulting in an infinite loop.

Here's a walk through of the reproducer. In this example, we're running `git log` against the file `main.go` which has the following content:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("example repository for demonstrating git log bug")
}
```

1. Start gdb and set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `while` loop in `line-range.c`. Arrange to print the value of `start` after each break:

   ```
   (gdb) break line-range.c:140
   Breakpoint 1 at 0x5a7a89: file line-range.c, line 140.
   (gdb) commands
   Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
   End with a line saying just "end".
   >p start
   >end
   (gdb)
   ```
2. Run `git log -L :$:main.go` under the control of gdb:

   ```
   (gdb) run log -L :$:main.go
   Starting program: /home/lars/src/git/git log -L :$:main.go
   [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
   Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
   [Detaching after fork from child process 2469232]

   Breakpoint 1, find_funcname_matching_regexp (xecfg=0x0, start=0x8477c0 "package main\n\nimport \"fmt\"\n\nfunc main() {\n\tfmt.Println(\"example repository for demonstrating git log bug\")\n}\n", regexp=0x7fffffffc020) at line-range.c:140
   140                     reg_error = regexec(regexp, start, 1, match, 0);
   $1 = 0x8477c0 "package main\n\nimport \"fmt\"\n\nfunc main() {\n\tfmt.Println(\"example repository for demonstrating git log bug\")\n}\n"
   ```

   In this output, we can see that `start` is pointing at the beginning of the file:

   ```
   $1 = 0x8477c0 "package main\n\nimport \"fmt\"\n\nfunc main() {\n\tfmt.Println(\"example repository for demonstrating git log bug\")\n}\n"
   ```
3. Skip a few iterations:

   ```
   (gdb) c 7
   Will ignore next 6 crossings of breakpoint 1.  Continuing.

   Breakpoint 1, find_funcname_matching_regexp (xecfg=0x0, start=0x84782b "}\n", regexp=0x7fffffffc020) at line-range.c:140
   140                     reg_error = regexec(regexp, start, 1, match, 0);
   $2 = 0x84782b "}\n"
   ```

   Here we see that `start` now points at the last line in the file.
4. Watch what happens if we iterate a few more times:

   ```
   (gdb) c
   Continuing.

   Breakpoint 1, find_funcname_matching_regexp (xecfg=0x0, start=0x84782d "", regexp=0x7fffffffc020) at line-range.c:140
   140                     reg_error = regexec(regexp, start, 1, match, 0);
   $3 = 0x84782d ""
   (gdb) c
   Continuing.

   Breakpoint 1, find_funcname_matching_regexp (xecfg=0x0, start=0x84782d "", regexp=0x7fffffffc020) at line-range.c:140
   140                     reg_error = regexec(regexp, start, 1, match, 0);
   $4 = 0x84782d ""
   (gdb) c
   Continuing.

   Breakpoint 1, find_funcname_matching_regexp (xecfg=0x0, start=0x84782d "", regexp=0x7fffffffc020) at line-range.c:140
   140                     reg_error = regexec(regexp, start, 1, match, 0);
   $5 = 0x84782d ""
   ```

   After one more iteration of the loop, `start` now points at the empty string. It keeps this value in every subsequent iteration, and we never break out of the `while` loop.

---

I've submitted a [patch to git](http://public-inbox.org/git/20221205193625.2424202-1-lars@oddbit.com/T/#u) that should correct this behavior.

You can follow the discussion there to see if they like my patch or if they decide there is a more appropriate way to resolve the problem.

With the patched version of the code, we see the following behavior instead:

```
$ git log -L :$:main.go
fatal: -L parameter '$' starting at line 1: no match
```

Comment: The patch has been accepted; it's currently in the [`next` branch](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e57c88e028c25ee9428b51ff829299bbb88a80c) and should show up in a future release.

Comment: It is on [`master` now](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f2e4c09c769dc2fbbabfcfa625451f9d98bd49a).